# Using Angular-CLI build to copy a file / directory

Tags: angular-cli

Is there a way to make angular-cli's `ng buil --prod` command to also copy a file/directory to the dist folder?

My project includes a "server" folder, and a "config.js" file at root, and I need them to be copied to "dist" such that when building, I don't need to remember to copy those directories

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On your angular-cli.json on assets object add the folders you want to include like:

Note : For Angular 9, this should be placed on angular.json file

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "META-INF",
    "WEB-INF"
  ]
```

Comment: i am trying to copy one directory but it is not get copied the directory is outside the `src` folder so i gave the path as `../my_dir` and i run the command `ng build --prod` and only `assets` and `favicon.ico` were copied to the `dist` folder `my_dir` folder was not copied.

Comment: I have the same problem as @HirenParekh. Any solution for that?

Comment: For Angular 9, this should be placed on `angular.json` file

Comment: The server build part in `angular.json` does not allow to copy assets because they assume that only the browser build (the SPA) should have assets. If you are building an Angular Universal App you will face this problem, still looking for a good solution.

Answer (score 63):

For those wanting to copy files outside the `src` folder:

In example below I am copying all files from `myfolder` to the root `dist` folder.

***In the angular-cli.json file (3rd line):***

```
"assets": [
   { "glob": "**/*", "input": "./assets/", "output": "./assets/" },
   { "glob": "favicon.ico", "input": "./", "output": "./" },
   { "glob": "**/*", "input": "../myfolder", "output": "./" }
],
```

[Angular-cli.json Documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md#writing-assets-outside-of-dist)

Comment: copy project.json file from root to dist { "glob": "project.json", "input": "./", "output": "/" }

Comment: Updated documentation link: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#asset-config

Answer (score 5):

**Source [Link](https://thecodemon.com/angular-how-to-move-copy-folder-files-during-project-build-process/)**

For **ng build** use the **"postbuild"** command to copy folder/files

Update the **package.json** file

**From**

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
....
```

},

**To**

```
"scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
   "start": "ng serve",
   "build": "ng build && npm run postbuild",
   "postbuild":"xcopy /s \".\/dist\\angular-material-bottom-sheet-app\" \".\/mydistapp\\dist\" \/Y",
   "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
```

Check complete details [here](https://thecodemon.com/angular-how-to-move-copy-folder-files-during-project-build-process/)

Comment: good solution with the postbuild step. remember that xcopy is deprecated. use robocopy https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: its probably best to not use any native bash commands since it will break depending on the OS. I would recommend looking for a good npm package that copies files like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles

Answer (score 0):

When you put it in src/assets/.htaccess, it will be copied into dist/assets/.htaccess.

If you want it to be in dist/.htaccess, then you should be in src/.htaccess AND you need to add it to angular-cli.json in the assets array (like favicon.ico).