# Integrating Keycloak with Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, keycloak

I am trying to configure an Angular (10) frontend to log in and out using Keycloak, but keep getting the following error in the console of Chrome dev tools:

```
    GET http://localhost:4200/keycloak.json 404 (Not Found)      zone-evergreen.js:2845
```

It seems that, despite explicitly stating the URL of the Keycloak server (running on my local system) in the code, the Angular app is trying to hit the login credentials in a dummy JSON file.

Many thanks in advance if anyone can suggest a way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your Angular program wants to read a keycloak.json file.
It can get it from Keycloak UI. And put in your angular "Local Development" root directory.
That file provides to Keycloak's configuration for Authz of Angular.
[image]

It's file actually did not copy `dist' directory. it is an actual angular running directory.

Please see the threat in angular questions.
[Using Angular-CLI build to copy a file / directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567449/using-angular-cli-build-to-copy-a-file-directory)